# How to get the listitem text value when click on it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a listitem and I would like to get the clicked item text value.  The following codes is not work for me.

It work fine, When I change the following line:

```
String fullname = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

To:

```
String fullname = "Hello world";
```

Thanks for your help.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String fullname = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Intent bucket = new Intent(SQLView.this, SQLView2.class);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("fullname", fullname);      
    bucket.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(bucket);
}
```

Here's the error I got on the LogCat

```
12-16 15:41:50.322: D/AndroidRuntime(279): Shutting down VM
12-16 15:41:50.322: W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.test.calculator.SQLView.onListItemClick(SQLView.java:52)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-16 15:41:50.352: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what at this line `ava.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code as if you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter` or `CursorAdapter` :

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    Cursor cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    String fullname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fullname"));

    Intent bucket = new Intent(SQLView.this, SQLView2.class);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("fullname", fullname);      
    bucket.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(bucket);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String fullname = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Comment: very nice, this is the way to go if you ask me

Answer (score 0):

[`getItemAtPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemIdAtPosition%28int%29) returns the `Object` that is associated with the given position.

So, check the class type that is being return (probably the one you provided) and use the class methods to grab the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

If the items are `TextView`s then use

```
String fullname = v.getText().toString();
```