# Cannot cast value in getItem

Tags: android, android-listview, casting

I am trying to get the value of an item from listview, but I receive a cast error when I try to "adapter.getItem(position)".

I am supposing that getItem function is where the error occurs, according to the log, but I'm not sure how else I can pass the value to a string?

The relevant code is:

```
public String getItem(int pos) {

        String myString = (String) adapter.getItem(pos);
        return myString;

    }

    private OnItemClickListener onAnswerClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                String getValue = getItem(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "Click ListItem Number " + getValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  .show();


        }

    };
```

The error I receive in logcat is:

```
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.sembasys.metrosleepnyc.ChooseRoute.getItem(ChooseRoute.java:61)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.sembasys.metrosleepnyc.ChooseRoute$1.onItemClick(ChooseRoute.java:72)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-18 10:50:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(18988):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your error is pretty obvious. The value returned from getItem(position) is a Cursor. you probably need to call String myString = getItem(position).getString(MY_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);

Comment: you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903013/how-to-get-the-listitem-text-value-when-click-on-it maybe helpful for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are passing Cursor to your ListView and casting String instead of Cursor. But, I would insist not to pass Cursor to ListView instead you can fetch the data from Cursor in some Collection maybe ArrayList and then pass ArrayList to the ListView's Adapter.